# Passing arguments to Asyntask

Tags: android, parameters, android-asynctask

I  have made a general class which extends Asynctask. Whenever I call Asynctask, I have 4 strings which I have to pass as parameter in asynctask which i can do further process depending on strings.
Is it possible to send 4 strings in asynctask?

Comment: pass it using doInBackground()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass them in AsyncTask's constructor as shown below:

```
public class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>{
    String s1, s2, s3, s4;

    public ProcessTask(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        s1 = str1;
        s2 = str2;
        s3 = str3;
        s4 = str4;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do something with strings
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //your code

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


}
```

Call as:

```
ProcessTask p =new ProcessTask(s1, s2, s3, s4);
p.execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way is, you can get the variable using constructor, pass variables while creating object.
for example,

```
public class SapleAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
public SapleAsynctask(String s1, String s2,  String s3, String s4) {
this.s1 = s1;
.
.
.
    }
}
```

If you want to get the data for `doInBackground()` you can pass the argument while calling the `asynctask.excecute([])` for this,

```
 public class SapleAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
S1 = params[0];
s2 = params[1];
.
.

        return false;
    }
}
```

And call the asynctask using

```
SapleAsynctask sapleAsynctask = new SapleAsynctask ();
sapleAsynctask .excecute(new String[] {"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** In your AsyncTask's doInBackground method parse params like that:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String s1 = params[0];
        String s2 = params[1];
        // ...

        return null;
    }
```

**Step 2.** When executing AsyncTask - pass String[] array:

```
myAsyncTask.execute(new String[] {s1, s2, s3, s4});
```

**Additional info.** It happens sometimes that you need to pass as parameters objects of different types. To achieve this you need to pass Object[] array like this:

```
myAsyncTask.execute(new Object[] {myObj1, s2, myObj3, s4});
```

and parse this array in your AsyncTask's doInBackground method like this:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        MyObject myObj1 = (MyObject) params[0];
        String s2 = (String) params[1];
        // ...

        return null;
    }
```